# I cannot wordwrap a UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have the following code

```
import UIKit

class BookDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let bookImage = UIImageView()
    let bookTitle = UILabel()
    let bookDesc = UILabel()
    let bookAuthor = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        contentView.addSubview(bookImage)
        contentView.addSubview(bookTitle)
        contentView.addSubview(bookDesc)
        contentView.addSubview(bookAuthor)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var frame = bookImage.frame
        frame.size.height = 150
        frame.size.width = 100
        frame.origin.x = 10
        frame.origin.y = 10
        bookImage.frame = frame

        var aframe = bookTitle.frame
        aframe.size.height = 26
        aframe.size.width = self.frame.size.width - 140
        aframe.origin.x = 130
        aframe.origin.y = 20
        bookTitle.frame = aframe
        bookTitle.textColor = UIColor(red:0.52, green:0.80, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0)
        bookTitle.font = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Bold", size: 16);


        bookDesc.textColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.31, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)
        bookDesc.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        bookDesc.numberOfLines = 0
        bookDesc.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 13);

        var bframe = bookDesc.frame
        bframe.size.height = 23
        bframe.size.width = self.frame.size.width - 140
        bframe.origin.x = 130
        bframe.origin.y = 56
        bookDesc.frame = bframe

        var cframe = bookAuthor.frame
        cframe.size.height = 23
        bookAuthor.textColor = UIColor.black
        cframe.size.width = self.frame.size.width - 140
        cframe.origin.x = 130
        cframe.origin.y = self.frame.size.height - 40
        bookAuthor.frame = cframe
        bookAuthor.font = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Regular", size: 13);
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Wordwrapping for UILabel does not word wrap for label bookDesc. Does anyone know why? Using XCode 10.0. Swift 5.0

I'm implementing UILabel programmatically not using the storyboard.

Comment: You are adding `bookDesc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` line, that means you have to set programatically constraint's for `bookDesc`, So where is that constraints?

Comment: ah thanks for letting me know. I removed it

Answer (score 0):

How can you say that linebreak mode doesn't work ? as you have provided fixed height of 23 in below code.

```
    var bframe = bookDesc.frame
    bframe.size.height = 23
```

**Linebreak** mode will not increase height for you when text is larger for that you have two options either apply a valid constraints to your all the views or calculate height based on text and change height of your label programatically

If you find difficulties in  constrains then use stackview

Hopefully this will help you to understand your problem with code

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting the word wrap option under the attributes inspector.

Comment: He has added label programatically.

Comment: I see that. I was trying to provide another option.